How to get Azure Virtual Machine data using ARM client using Azure/azure-sdk-for-net samples
Exploring some C# samples on GitHub here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net in order to learn how to use the ARM client to read certain metadata from Azure environments.
In the sample linked below, I am trying to query Azure Virtual machines in a tenant. When I follow the sample, the code hangs for less than 3 mins and then eventually times out with a bad gateway error here await foreach (ComputeResourceSku item in subscriptionResource.GetComputeResourceSkusAsync()).

Any advice or updates samples I should be following?
Example permalink.
Source:
        // Lists all available Resource SKUs
        [NUnit.Framework.Test]
        [NUnit.Framework.Ignore("Only verifying that the sample builds")]
        public async Task GetComputeResourceSkus_ListsAllAvailableResourceSKUs()
        {
            // Generated from example definition: specification/compute/resource-manager/Microsoft.Compute/Skus/stable/2021-07-01/examples/skus/ListAvailableResourceSkus.json
            // this example is just showing the usage of "ResourceSkus_List" operation, for the dependent resources, they will have to be created separately.

            // get your azure access token, for more details of how Azure SDK get your access token, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication?tabs=command-line
            TokenCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();
            // authenticate your client
            ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);

            // this example assumes you already have this SubscriptionResource created on azure
            // for more information of creating SubscriptionResource, please refer to the document of SubscriptionResource
            string subscriptionId = "{subscription-id}";
            ResourceIdentifier subscriptionResourceId = SubscriptionResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId);
            SubscriptionResource subscriptionResource = client.GetSubscriptionResource(subscriptionResourceId);

            // invoke the operation and iterate over the result
            await foreach (ComputeResourceSku item in subscriptionResource.GetComputeResourceSkusAsync())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded: {item}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded");
        }


Issue was with my role assignment for the application registration my arm client depends on. This is a quick fix and look forward to seeing if there are more granular or least privileged roles the community here can provide.
az role assignment create --assignee "<OBJECT_ID_OR_PRINCIPAL_ID>" --role "Contributor" --scope "/"

